# Adicionar dados do QtableView no banco de dados

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtgui

Olá.
Como que faço para adicionar todos os dados de dentro `tableView` no banco de dados?

Estou adicionando dados no `tableView` com `QStandardItem`

```
//TableView 
count =  ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->count();
verticalHeader.append(QString::number(count + 1));
model.setVerticalHeaderLabels(verticalHeader);

item00 = new QStandardItem(ui->comboBox->currentText());
model.setItem(count, 0, item00);
ui->tableView->setModel(&model);

//insert sqlite
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO entrada (entrada_produto) VALUES (?)");
qry.addBindValue(ui->comboBox->currentText());
qry.exec();
```

Comment: Você deveria dar uma olhada [nesse link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sql-presenting.html).

Comment: No link só informa como fazer o update no campo selecionado. Eu quero adicionar todos dados do tableView no db.

Comment: Sem mais detalhes do DB fica dificil. Ponha o que você já tentou, aí da pra ajudar melhor.

Comment: @Bacco Olá. O que gostaria é pegar cada linha(row) apenas uma coluna do `tableView` e adicionar no db. `DB = | id PRIMARY KEY | lista |` Editei o Post com código adicional.

Comment: @Bacco Sqlite. Post atualizado.

Comment: @user628298 pus uma versão baseada na sua, com a query junto, caso alguém leia a resposta e queira a versão completa.

Comment: Blz. Sem problema, pode deixa seu código :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido:

```
    int col = ui->tableView_pedido->verticalHeader()->count();

    for (int i = 0; i < col ; ++i){
        QString pedido = ui->tableView_pedido->model()->data(ui->tableView_pedido->model()->index(i,0)).toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int col = ui->tableView_pedido->verticalHeader()->count();

QSqlQuery qry;
QString pedido;
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO pedidos (pedido) VALUES (:pedido)");

for (int i = 0; i < col ; i++){
   pedido = ui->tableView_pedido->model()->data(
      ui->tableView_pedido->model()->index(i,0)
   ).toString()
   qry.bindValue(":pedido",pedido); // Creio que pode ser tirado do loop também.
   qry.exec();
}
```

Comment: (este é o mesmo código do user628298, acrescentei a query propriamente dita)